# Robolectric 2 with JNI

Tags: android, maven, java-native-interface, robolectric

In my app I stared using an external library that uses JNI.

```
System.loadLibrary("somelib")
```

Also I have unitests with `Robolectric 2`. When I'm running these tests I'm getting the following exception:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no dafprovider in java.library.path
```

**How to configure `Robolectric` to load this native library?**
Note: I'm using `Maven`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, **Robolectric** doesn't work with JNI. My suggestion would be to wrap JNI library loading into class and mock it under the test, or override JNI method loading in test:

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
   public void onCreate() {
      loadJNI();
   }

   protected void loadJNI() {
      System.loadLibrary("somelib");
   }
}
```

in tests:

```
public class TestMyApp extends MyApp {
    @Override
    protected void loadJNI() {
      //don't do anything
    }
}
```